# awk to parse field if specific value is in another

Tags: awk

In the `awk` below I am trying to parse `$2` using the `_` only if `$3` is a specific valus (ID). I am reading that parsed value into an array and going to use it as a key in a lookup. The `awk` does execute but the entire line 2 or line with `ID` in `$3` prints not just the desired. The print statement is only to see what results (for testing only) and will not be part of the script. Thank you :).

**awk**

```
awk -F'\t' '$3=="ID"
            f="$(echo $2|cut -d_ -f1,1)"
            {
            print $f
            }' file
```

**file**  `tab-delimited`

```
R_Index locus   type
17  chr20:31022959  NON
18  chr11:118353210-chr9:20354877_KMT2A-MLLT3.K8M9  ID
```

**desired**

```
$f = chr11:118353210-chr9:20354877
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not completely clear, could you please try following.

```
awk '{split($2,array,"_");if(array[2]=="KMT2A-MLLT3.K8M9"){print array[1]}}' Input_file
```

Or if you want top change 2nd field's value along with printing all lines then try following once.

```
awk '{split($2,array,"_");if(array[2]=="KMT2A-MLLT3.K8M9"){$2=array[1]}} 1' Input_file
```

Comment: Thank you very much :).